# 404 Eror API Call Pexels Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-requests

I want to download an image with Pexels API ([documentation](https://www.pexels.com/api/documentation)) with Python. First, I get the ID of the picture by doing:

```
import requests
image_base_url = 'https://api.pexels.com/v1/search'
api_key = 'my_api_key'
my_obj = {'query':'Stock market'}
x = requests.get(image_base_url,headers = {'Authorization':api_key},data = my_obj)
print(x.text)
```

Then, I obtain an ID for the image I want and run this:

```
photo_request_link = 'https://api.pexels.com/v1/photos/'
photo_id = {'id':159888}
final_photo = requests.get(photo_request_link,headers = {'Authorization':api_key},data=photo_id)
print(final_photo)
```

But get 404 Error as a result. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id is a part of the URL path, not the querystring. See the example in the documentation (https://api.pexels.com/v1/photos/2014422). You should append it to the URL, for example:

```
photo_request_link = f'https://api.pexels.com/v1/photos/{id}'
```